# How can I improve this rice recipe

Tags: rice

I have an older instant pot pressure cooker (ip-lux50 v3) and I've tried making rice according to various recipes I've found on the internet and none of them have turned out well

This is one recipe I've tried

https://www.pressurecookrecipes.com/instant-pot-rice/

The rice came out gummy and stuck to the pot. I'm hoping for suggestions of a way to make good rice based on this recipe

Comment: This is strange. Are you sure you used jasmine rice? Does the same brand of rice provide better results with other cooking methods?

Answer (score 2):

The rice can make the difference. The rice:water ratio can make the difference.
I don't know the figures for Jasmine, but quite famously half the bags of Basmati sold are not, in fact, Basmati. See The [Great Rice Scam](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/food-and-drink/features/great-rice-scam-5368758.html).

The images shown on that site give the impression they do aim for 'slightly sticky' so you can pick up with chopsticks.

First tests would be…
Reduce your water content.
Let it sit an additional 15 minutes once finished.
Experiment with leaving the lid on vs removing it & placing a sheet of kitchen roll over the top with the lid on just enough to hold it flat. [Greek/Turkish method]

Personally, I never rinse rice & I never use anything other than a regular saucepan. Perfect rice every time, in 30 minutes.

1 : 1.6 rice : water. [more than a pressure cooker of course]
Drop boiling water onto ready-salted rice in a pre-heated pan. This causes a flash boil which immediately separates the grains.
Quick stir once. Heat to minimum, lid on.
15 minutes at lowest heat.
Switch off. Leave 15 minutes more.
Done.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar electric pressure cooker and a budget price basmati rice turns out perfect (1 mug measure of rice to 1 mug measure of water, 3 minutes maximum pressure, natural release, about 5-8 minutes total). I don't even have non-stick insert, and the rice comes away freely from the bottom. If anything, the rice is very slightly under cooked (al dente) rather than over cooked.

1. Are you soaking the rice beforehand? This will cause the rice to be overcooked
2. What colour is the rice? Glutinous rice is pearly white, the non-glutinous variety is more translucent. The former will give you sticky rice
3. Are all the seals of your pressure cooker functioning OK (not damaged or cut or twisted in any way) and all the valves clear of food debris etc? If these are blocked or the pressure cooker is malfunctioning, it may be overheating/over pressurised. Does other food cook as you would expect it to?
4. Is the base of the pan insert clean? I have heard of people having problems due to dirt and cooking debris building up here. Is the pot insert seated properly? If it is not making proper contact with the base, the pressure cooker could possibly be overheating, thereby scorching the rice.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a problem with the recipe. The most common sign of a bad recipe for a pressure cooker would be rice that turns out too mushy. Gummy rice is usually about the starch.

So, to troubleshoot:

1. Make sure that you have picked a recipe intended to produce the type of rice you want. Tetsujin already noted that this recipe is geared towards a slightly sticky result. If you want absolute nonstickiness, you should choose a recipe optimized for that.
2. The recipe you have is for jasmine rice. If you used a different cultivar, make sure that you are using jasmine rice, or switch to a recipe for the cultivar of rice you have. And of course, don't use parboiled rice or rice preprocessed in other ways, this is a recipe intended for plain raw rice.
3. If your rice is labeled as jasmine, but the recipe still fails, consider buying another brand. I have had brands which produced a terrible result, no matter what technique I tried with them.
4. You will generally reduce stickiness by more rinsing. Don't stop when the water is clear as the recipe directs you, continue rinsing for some time after that even if you don't notice the starch.
5. Make sure that you eat the rice fresh. Standing at fridge temperatures quickly changes the texture towards gumminess.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend rinsing your rice if it’s coming out gummy:

Put some water in a bowl with the rice (just barely enough to cover it), stir it with your hand, drain, then repeat a couple more times.

Be careful when you’re pouring out the water as you can accidentally dump the rice, too.  I usually try to intentionally get the rice to bunch up in the direction I’m pouring, then pour it over my hand slowly, so I can catch it if the rice starts to fall out.

The first rinse will usually be milky as there’s so much free starch in it.  Later rinses will become more clear.  You can then use a strainer to drain it fully, or decrease the water slightly to deal with the extra water.

(Although it’s basically 1:1 when cooking in a non-jiggling pressure cooker, you also need just a little bit more that leaks out until it pressurizes, but if it’s still coming out gummy, you can try reducing the water slightly)